# how do I find out if a placed order was deleted or trashed?

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I am looking for a order number #2099 in woo-commerce, the order does not show and it's missing (skipped from #2098 to #2100). The order of number should always be there unless it was deleted or If the order got cancel. 
How do I look for the trash bin?
I understand if it was trashed you have 30 days to recover it or undo the deletion right away.
But in this case none of this steps (delete/trash) was performed and they should have a history.  Please help

Comment: A quick search on Google would have revealed the answer to this - https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=woocommerce+order+numbers+missing

Answer (score 1):

WooCommerce order numbers are not sequential as the orders share WordPress' posts table in the database. The posts table in the database is shared with posts, pages, draft posts/pages, images/media etc.

So, if you had an order and then a post, page, draft or image was created then it would have taken, in your example ID #2099. Then your next order was stored as ID #2100.

If this is a problem for you then there are plugins available that will make your order numbers sequential to help prevent any confusion in the future. One example is - [WooCommerce Sequential Order Numbers](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-sequential-order-numbers/)